# Checking Data on a form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Im new to c# so not sure if there is an easier way.

I have created 5 forms, Form 1 is my main form, form 2,3,4 and 5 are data entry forms.

The user chooses which form or forms they wish to enter data, can choose all 4 or just one.

I want to control all 4 forms from form one (I do not want windows to pop up). The user must just see one form then the data form they are entering. They can jump between forms by pressing a button. I have created panel for each form and load each for the user ticks. I then hide all the forms expect the latest, The user can then click the button he wishes and the panel is displayed hiding the others.... I need to ensure if the user enters data in any form the data validation checks are enforced, currently if the user close form 1 then the data is lost with no warning. CHow can I perform data integrity checks a form loaded in a panel. [image]

Comment: say **4 forms from form one** 3 times quickly!

Comment: I think you should may be break down your problems in steps each with a code sample; divide and conquer style; it would be less time consuming for people to understand your problem probably

Comment: Ok as it stands if you see the image, the yellow fields need data. The form one of the data entry forms and I have added it into a panel .  see code                                    EditQuote tf1 = new EditQuote(0, 0, true);
                    tf1.TopLevel = false;

                    panel1.Controls.Add(tf1);
                    panel2.Width = 1;
                    tf1.Show();   I do not want form1 to close unless the yellow boxes are entered. From form1 how do I access a field in the edit form.

Comment: Are you using a mdi application with mdi childs? I think this could help you and do things easier...

Comment: no just a panel from the toolbox and adding the form to there.... I will look into mdi see if I have any luck...

Comment: only thought on mdi forms, can you have more than one form open at once. I.e if I use panels, I hide a panel but the data is still there only hidden, i can then hop between my forms partially adding the data. Then if possible if I close the main form it checks all the open forms in the panels that all the data fields are complete, if not then an error. with mdi forms does it allow you to have more than one open,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UserControl.

1) convert form2,form3,form4 to UserControl (lets say anymore uc2,uc3,uc4)

2) When user presses for uc3, unvisible uc2,uc4, set visible uc3

I think this is what you look for.

Comment: ive looked in parent and child mdi and its looks possible I can do it this way, my child form has error checking and if I try to close it will prompt are you sure etc. If I close the parent mdi it just closes. How can I get  a parent mdi to only close if the child is error free?

Comment: I could not understand clearly but you can set a static value in child class and check it in parent class such as
 `if(uc3.isError == false)`

//do something

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your requirement correctly then you can use Tab control in windows Forms

here are some reference link for Tabcontrol [Tab Control link1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e881fb/learn-tab-control-using-C-Sharp/)

[TabControl Link2](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tabcontrol)